# What would happen if we try to use an N-degree polynomial to interpolate N data points?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I know that given an N-degree polynomial interpolating N+1 points [exists and is unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Uniqueness_of_the_interpolating_polynomial). However, I am wondering what would happen if we try to use an N-degree polynomial to interpolate N data points.

I think that in that case, we would have more equations than unknowns which is considered an overdetermined system (and is most likely inconsistent). We would then have to use other methods such as least squared fit instead of polynomial interpolation (and approximate instead of interpolate).

Any hints? Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Looks to me the other way round - that it is under-determined and thus you have a free variable. Think of the ways to pass a degree-$1$ polynomial (a line) through a single point.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I see what you're saying but I read that a system is overdetermined if there are more equations than unknowns. I think that in this case there's an extra equation to satisfy and it's likely to "fail" as the system most likely doesn't have a solution. Why do you say there's a free variable? I thought there exists a free variable if, say, if two equations reduce into one. I'm most likely to be wrong though so open for comments.

Comment: There isn't an extra equation, there is an extra variable. Back to my example, if you want a degree-$1$ polynomial (i.e. a line $y=ax+b$) through the single point $(2,3)$, you have an equation $3=2a+b$ and so you can, for example, freely choose $a$ (as long as $b=3-2a$).

Comment: Another way to see it: fix a value $x_{N+1}$ different from all the $x$ coordinates of your $N$ points, pick an *arbitrary* value $y_{N+1}$ and then pass the (unique) Lagrange polynomial of degree $N$ through those $N+1$ points. By varying $y_{N+1}$ you can vary through all those polynomials of degree $N$ through the first $N$ points (after all, every such polynomial must have *some* value at $x_{N+1}$...) - so you get a family of solutions of your original problem - parameterised by $y_{N+1}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thank you so much!

Comment: do you have an answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606499/finding-an-interpolation-polynomial-of-degree-greater-than-n1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are on the right track.  If you consider a simple case of two points (N=2) and a second degree polynomial (parabola), you can see that different parabolas will be able to fit the two points, yet have vastly different possible values in the interpolated region.  Therefore, some additional constraint on the parabola would be needed for the interpolation to be meaningful under some criteria.  I hope this helps.