# Finding an interpolation polynomial of degree greater than n+1

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

The degree of an interpolation polynomial of n data points is n-1. However, this is THE interpolation polynomial. If we have already found it, how can we build an interpolation polynomial for the same data points of degree n or n+1? Any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Add an extra point, interpolate the new polynomial on the new set of points.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Are you just asking a computational question?  If so, there is no difficulty just adding  a random point $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ to the interpolating data and interpolating again.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any expression $$q(x)\prod_{k=1}^n(x-x_k),$$ $q$ being some polynomial, to the interpolation polynomial and get another polynomial that takes the same values at the sample points $x_k$.